# require is not defined javascript xmlhttrequest

Tags: api, undefined, xmlhttprequest

Buen dia, espero que esten bien todos, estoy aprendiendo sobre programaciòn y veia un video sobre callbacks y como hacer una peticion a una api publica de rickandmorty, pero me surge este error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
  
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fcckkdbjnoikooededlapcalpionmalo/static/js/pageHook.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Y este es el codigo:

```
 let XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
   
 let API = 'https://rickandmorty.com/api/character/';

    function fetchData(url_api, callback) {
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open('GET', url_api, true);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
            if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhttp.status === 200) {
                    callback(null, JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));
                }else{
                    const error = new Error('Error ' + url_api);
                    return callback(error, null)
                }
            }
        }
        xhttp.send();
    }
    fetchData(API, function (error1, data1){
        if (error1) return console.error(error1);
        fetchData(API + data1.results[0].id, function(error2,data2){
            if (error2) return console.error(error2);
            fetchData(data2.origin.url, function(error3, data3){
                if (error3) return console.error(error3);
                console.log(data1.info.count);
                console.log(data2.name);
                console.log(data3.dimension);
            })
        })
    });
```

Comment: Supongo estás ejecutando el código en el navegador, pero estás usando sintaxis de `node`. El `require` no existe en el navegador por eso el error que te da. Por otro lado te recomiendo usar mejor la api de `fetch` o `axios`, su sintaxis es mucho más moderna y sencilla.

Comment: Si estás en el navegador, el objeto [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) está disponible de forma nativa sin necesidad de usar `require`. Elimina esa primera línea de tu código y funcionará. Tal como te comentan, `require` es un método usado por NodeJS para la carga de módulos, aunque puedes usarlo en el navegador configurando una librería llamada [`requirejs`](https://requirejs.org/). Saludos